# glmer error - PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

Tags: r, statistics

I am using `glmer` in R to run a binomial model to predict pre-term birth using lab test.

lab test is separated into two variables: **lab_order** that can take 0 (the lab test was not ordered) or 1 (the lab test was ordered) and **lab_result** which is a numeric variable with the result of the test.

I did it in this way to adjust by the fact that the **lab_result** can be ordered or not ordered. 
In addition, the lab test can be taken in different weeks of the pregnancy, so I am adding a random effect with the `patient_index` to account for the repeating test at different weeks for the same individual.

The model I run is very simple:

`glmer(Term ~ lab_order + scale(lab_result) +                   (1|Patient_index),family=binomial)`

but I obtained the following error:

`Error in pwrssUpdate(pp, resp, tol = tolPwrss, GQmat = GQmat, compDev = compDev,  : 
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate`

I have run it with and without scaling the numeric variable, because I read that this error may be because of a scaling problem, but the error is not solved anyway.

Any ideas of what is going on?

Comment: what are the values of `lab_result` when `lab_order` is 0?  Are they set to `NA`?

Comment: also: is the value of the `Term` the same for every observation of a given patient?